# Entity Framework refer to an entity in the DB without adding it again

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, addition

I have two entities, a project and a company.
One company has a list of multiple projects and a project has one company.

At this time I'm adding a existing company from the DB to project

e.g.

```
project.company = getCompanyByName("Microsoft");
```

Which returns the proper company and does add it to my project.

However, when I add this new project to the DB as such:

```
ctx.AddToProjects(project);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

It will also add a second Microsoft company 
So how do I make my project refer to the existing company without adding it, again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the Company to the context before you associate it with a Project.

Once the Company is safely in the context, actions that you perform on the Projects won't affect its state.